# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with() - Larvel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a query below but it throws the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

What could I be missing out ?

PS: Beginner with Laravel

**Item.php**

```
  public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }
        

    public function displayShopResults()
{
    $connection = DB::connection('mysql2');

    return $connection->table('items')->with('shop')->select('created_at','chat_id',DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('SUM(received_item) as received,SUM(sold_item) as sold)
            ->whereMonth('created_at','=',Carbon::now()->format('m'))
            ->get();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent

```
public function displayShopResults()
{
        return self::with('shop')->select('created_at','chat_id',DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('SUM(received_item) as received,SUM(sold_item) as sold')
            ->whereMonth('created_at','=',Carbon::now()->format('m'))
            ->get();

}
```